# Autosize GridViewColumns programmatically by content

Tags: c#, wpf, gridviewcolumn

I want to set programmatically my GridViewColumns to autosize by content, not by header (Width = double.NaN)

I have searched for a long time and I found this problem solved with DataGridColumns, but how is this with GridViewColumns ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, found a good hint on it [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ca465989-462c-412f-8f1c-1ab27239aea2/programmatically-resize-gridviews-columns?forum=wpf).

This is how I solved the problem.

```
if ((sender as ListView)?.View is GridView gridview)
{
    foreach (var column in gridview.Columns)
    {
        // Set the Width. Then clear it to cause the autosize.
        column.Width = 1;
        column.ClearValue(GridViewColumn.WidthProperty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach (DataGridColumn column in grid.Columns) {
      column.Width = DataGridLength.SizeToCells;
}
```

Comment: I have GridViewColumns from a GridView in a ListView, not DataGridColumns from a DataGrid